# How to select multiple controls inside a DelphiXE6 VCL groupbox by dragging the mouse?

Tags: delphi, ide, vcl, delphi-xe6

Delphi XE6 VCL Application.

Normally you can select multiple controls in one sweep by dragging the mouse over them to form a selection rectangle. Then you can move all of them together. However I seem to be unable to do that to a bunch of controls inside a groupbox. Everytime I try it I end up dragging the entire groupbox which is not what I want to do. Is there a trick that I'm unaware of or a designer option maybe. I don't know, seems odd that I've never encountered this before. If anyone can help (I already know how to select them individually by holding down the shift key) that would be nice.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this either. I think you're just stuck with it.

Comment: Hold Ctrl and drag the selection rectangle to surround the controls. Release the mouse when they're all surrounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting, then you are up and running.

Just for the record: This trick is not specific to newer version sof Delphi. It also worked in Delphi 6 (just tested it)

Comment: In fact it's a nearly ubiquitous pattern in all windows user interfaces, and is part of the CUA specification.